# aws emr add-steps a spark application

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I'd like to add a step as a spark application using AWS CLI, but I cannot find a working command, from AWS official doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html, they listed out 6 examples, none of them is for spark.
But I could configure it through AWS Console UI and it runs fine, but for efficiency, I'd like to be able to do so via aws cli.

The closest that I could come up with is this command:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-cluster-id --steps  Type=SPARK,Name='SPARK APP',ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://my-test/RandomJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,MainClass=JavaParquetExample1,Args=s3://my-test/my-file_0000_part_00.parquet,my-test --profile my-test --region us-west-2
```

but this resulted in this configuration on AWS EMR step:

```
JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None
Arguments : spark-submit s3://my-test/my-file_0000_part_00.parquet my-test
Action on failure: Continue
```

which resulted in failure.

The correct one (completed successfully, configured through AWS Console UI) looks like this:

```
JAR location : command-runner.jar
Main class : None
Arguments : spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class sparkExamples.JavaParquetExample1 s3://my-test/RandomJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --s3://my-test/my-file_0000_part_00.parquet --my-test
Action on failure: Continue
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this documentation contains valid examples or I may have not understood your query
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

Comment: what would be your command following which example in this link? thanks

Comment: Can you see logs for specific problem ( by going to Steps, selecting your step, and then, for Log files, choosing either stdout or stderr)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for me. I am adding a spark application to a cluster with the step name `My step name`. Let's say you name the file as `step-addition.sh`. The content of it is following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

#cluster id
clusterId=$1
startDate=$2
endDate=$3

aws emr add-steps --cluster-id $clusterId --steps Type=Spark,Name='My step name',\
ActionOnFailure=TERMINATE_CLUSTER,Args=[\
"--deploy-mode","cluster","--executor-cores","1","--num-executors","20","--driver-memory","10g","--executor-memory","3g",\
"--class","your-package-structure-like-com.a.b.c.JavaParquetExample1",\
"--master","yarn",\
"--conf","spark.driver.my.custom.config1=my-value-1",\
"--conf","spark.driver.my.custom.config2=my-value-2",\
"--conf","spark.driver.my.custom.config.startDate=${startDate}",\
"--conf","spark.driver.my.custom.config.endDate=${endDate}",\
"s3://my-bucket/my-prefix/path-to-your-actual-application.jar"]
```

You can execute the above script simply like this:

```
bash $WORK_DIR/step-addition.sh $clusterId $startDate $endDate
```